# Are bbpress questions off-topic here?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a couple of bbpress questions on the site, but I don't know if there is a consensus on whether or not they are within scope the scope of acceptable questions here (or if this depends on the question having an explicit Wordpress tie-in).

Comment: As far as I'm concerned bbPress questions are in scope for the site.

Answer (score 6):

As other questions they are on topic if they relate to WordPress. If your concern is about bbPress being separate project - it is being (slowly and obscurely) [migrated to be WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bbpress/), so as for me it makes little sense to exclude it for that.