# Are BackPress questions welcome here?

Tags: discussion

Related: [Are bbpress questions off-topic here?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/are-bbpress-questions-off-topic-here)

I'm working on a BackPress project, and - as there doesn't seem to be any active channels for support for BackPress - wondered if this was an appropriate place to ask questions. It doesn't seem as though any of the core BP people are active on here (correct me if I'm wrong), but most questions that would come up would be relevant to the functioning of WordPress as a whole.

Pros:

- most of the questions that would come up relate to a deeper understanding of how WP functions work (I'm specifically dealing with issues in the WP HTTP API that WP & BuddyPress experts may be able to help with)
- As there aren't any other open channels for BP hackers, this could be a place to gather knowledge and provide support for more people to start BP projects.

Cons:

- Its an extreme edge case, not many people seem to be actively hacking BackPress, every implementation is going to be different, etc.
- Might not add much to the average WP user's experience on this site, might confuse things.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't ask if you can ask questions, just ask ;) If community members are able to answer your question I'm sure no-one wants to delete them.

Comment: Ha. Good way of putting it. I did already ask, was just wondering for general discussion and future direction...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My vote for BackPress here is **Yes**.

-Mike

Comment: I don't oppose BackPress questions here, but I get the impression that we don't have enough experts here (yet) for the (formerly) sister projects like bbPress, WordPress MU, BackPress, ... Maybe we should do some targeted recruiting in those communities to get them over here?

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Without relevant questions we are unlikely to ever have relevant experts.

Comment: Indeed, it's a chicken and egg situation. And I don't have an objective overview whether this is really a problem. It would require someone to collect per-tag stats to see whether `[wordpress-mu]` and related tags have more unanswered questions than others.

Comment: I'll ask questions as I have them, and try to monitor those tags to help out where I can. Since there's really no other place set up for those questions to be asked (although there are a few experts and some activity on the buddypress suport forums), this seems as good a place as any. We'll just have to see if it takes off or not.

Answer (score 1):

I develop on MU all the time. Given that it is specifically built into trunk now, it should be a given that MU is covered.

If backpress questions are specifically about WP functionality, it makes sense for it to go here the same as any question about WP specific stuff. If the question was about bbpress isolated from WP, that might be a call to point the questioner to a new resource such as IRC.