# Does Wordpress Answers also support BuddyPress and bbPress?

Tags: discussion

With some of the changes in the FAQ regarding plugins are we or do we offer support for bbPress and BuddyPress? As they both were recently switched to plugins for WordPress CMS.

Reason for asking is that I, myself just recently started using both of these for clients and I'm sure eventually I and or someone else will have questions arrise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the question did arise a long time ago [Are bbpress questions off-topic here?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/are-bbpress-questions-off-topic-here) :)

I think given total experience up to now it's fair to summarize situation as following:

- the sheer fact of plugin/theme being involved does **not** make question out of scope
- such questions can **easily** fall out of scope by being too localized
- given that experts in specific extensions are much less numerous than WP in general, chances of such questions getting good answers are below average (so far)

Comment: Ahh ok. Well it is good to know that they won't really be off topic then. I actually did look at the link you posted prior to posting but was not sure if anything had changed. Especially since both bbPress and BuddyPress are now plugins. Now developing a plugin for the plugins ... That possibly could get sticky. lol :)